# VS Code: Output is only written in Terminal Window

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Im relatively new to programming and just started learning with VS Code.
When I want to output a simple line of code in VSCode in Python e.g.

```
print("Hello World!")
```

what happens is that all the output is shown in the terminal window (with a bunch of more information like base(user), the path and so on). Only in between somewhere its written "Hello World!".

How is it possible to display the output in a "clean" way?

I am using a Conda environment. No code runner extension is installed (since this behaviour was present for people who use this extension).
I read that you can add some code to your launch.json file. Where do I find that file and is that really necessary? The output then gets shown in the debugger part. Is that correct and why not in the output window? Where is this "bug" coming from? I expected the output "Hello World" to be shown in the Output window of VSCode in a clean way.

by the way I am not bound to use VSCode. But I thought to get used to a industry standard relatively early would be beneficial. If there are other recommendations feel free to add an alternative environment.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

1. install [code runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)
2. make sure "run in terminal" is unchecked
3. use shortcut ctrl + opt + n to run the code clean in the output window